# Relative pronouns usage when I am talking about myself

Tags: relative-pronouns

I don't know which one of these statements is correct:

> I am a hardworking person, who is always using the latest
>   techniques and technologies as good as **I** can.

Or

> I am a hardworking person, who is always using the latest
>   techniques and technologies as good as **He(or She)** can.

Comment: How about ". . . as *well* as I can"?

Comment: @Robusto I'm not sure about the difference! but my problem is using I or He/she.

Comment: You need to be sure about such things. What I pointed out was a worse problem than the one you're asking about.

Comment: I, you, he, she, we, they are NOT relative pronouns, they are subject pronouns. Please do some minimal research before posting very basic questions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "who" is the relative pronoun in the question!!!!!!!! I don't know why you think I didn't know something like that and down-vote the question!

Comment: "Relative pronouns" is plural, there is only one *who* in your post, I surmised you were referring to the subject **pronouns**. I downvoted for lack of research. You accepted an answer because it offered "I can", a very simple answer.

Comment: @Robusto gave you the answer 10 minutes after you posted your question AND supplied the correct adverb *well*

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's the topic! My question is about using all of the relative pronouns when I want talking about myself, this one is just a sample and I don't know how it is related to the lack of research! By the way I get the answer and I don't care anything else. Stackexchange is a community for Q&A.

Comment: How can you talk about yourself using "he" or "she"? [Where can I find answers to simple and basic questions? ... Of course, if your question isn't adequately answered by these resources, feel free to ask here on English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. **Be sure to mention the research you've done and what you're still hoping to learn!**](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28775/discussion-between-saman-gholami-and-mari-lou-a).

Comment: Not so terrible a question. I think the OP wants to know whether the relative pronoun in this sentence would make you parse it as follows: "I am a hardworking guy. This hardworking guy uses the latest techniques and technologies as well as he can." Or: "I am a hardworking guy. I use the latest techniques and technologies as well as I can."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this correct? "One of the things that makes him great is..."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232255/is-this-correct-one-of-the-things-that-makes-him-great-is)

Comment: I find it interesting that effectively the same issue arises in [*one of those people who **like***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22one+of+those+people+who+like%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) vs [*one of those people who **likes***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22one+of+those+people+who+likes%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), where both versions get over 800 hits in Google Books. With such high usage figures for *both* forms, I think it's pedantic and fatuous to suggest that either is in any meaningful sense "wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a hardworking person, who is always using the latest techniques and technologies as **well** as I can.

You can use 'I'.

As for he or she - that depends on whether the writer is male or female. There is no need to be gender-neutral when you know the sex of the person.

EDIT

In response to a comment I'll add the following. I assumed that the person referred to at the end of the sentence was the writer of the sentence. That doesn't have to be true, e.g.

I, John, I am a hardworking person, who is always using the latest techniques and technologies as well as Mary can.

In that case, if we didn't know the name/gender of the second person, the problem returns. However it is unusual to have a situation in which you compare yourself to an individual whose name/gender you don't know. In fact if you had a particular person in mind and weren't sure of their gender, it would probably be insulting to say 'he or she'.

Comment: I thought the OP was looking for a pronoun that could be used for either sex. If the other person's sex is unknown, what would you have suggested? However, it seems the OP accepted this answer for the "I can", in which case the question is general reference, and off-topic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Ah yes, good point. I engaged in some mind-reading there. I'll add to my answer.