# Relative clause - "...one of those people who make” or “makes"?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, relative-clauses

Which one is correct?

> He is not one of those people who **make**/**makes** you angry

Does "make" refer to  "one"? Is there a  possibility that "make" refers to "people"?

Can it be something relative?

Comment: The relative clause modifies "people" and thus the verb should be "make", There is a set of  people who make you angry, and he is not a member of this set.

Comment: This is about your question: https://www.oxonianreview.org/wp/one-of-those-grammatical-errors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say *one of those*, what follows is a group. The only thing you need to consider is the phrase that describes the group that comes after *those*. Since it is a group, the noun is plural.

> He is not one of those [plural noun phrase].

If the noun phrase includes a verb, then subject-verb agreement needs to follow the plural conjugation.

So:

> He is not one of those [**lawyers**].
> He is not one of those [**examples** of high society].
> He is not one of those [drunken **party-goers** who **stay** up all night].

And finally:

> He is not one of those [**people** who **make** you angry.]

---

Some comments have led me to add more to this.

As for what follows *one of those* being a plural, what you are doing is saying that *X* is a single selection from a group of two or more things. It's roughly the equivalent of the phrase *one of many*.

Some examples show the syntactical problem with using the singular:

> ✘ I'm eating *one of those* red ***jellybean***.
> ✘ I'm eating *one of many* red ***jellybean***.
>
> ✔ I'm eating *one of those* red ***jellybeans***.
> ✔ I'm eating *one of many* red ***jellybeans***.
>
> ✘ I'm going to *one of those* ***movie***.
> ✘ I'm going to *one of many* ***movie***.
>
> ✔ I'm going to *one of those* ***movies***.
> ✔ I'm going to *one of many* ***movies***.

If it doesn't make sense to use the singular as a general syntactical rule, it shouldn't make sense in any specific case either. (I grant that there are always exceptions, but I'm not aware of any here.)

---

Given that language is fluid, things that sound right to many people, and which are used by many people, become grammatical—even if they didn't start off as so. Further, some things that are not syntactically correct are still semantically fine and used as a matter of normal discourse.

However, in terms of looking at the following, the *syntax* is wrong—regardless of if you think it's *acceptable* to phrase them as they are:

> - [✘](https://books.google.it/books?id=Q5li4S0bpAwC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22He%20is%20one%20of%20those%20who%20has%20had%20the%20wilderness%20for%20a%20pillow,%20and%20called%20a%20star%20his%20brother.%22&source=bl&ots=ax0R92ScTb&sig=ACfU3U0KIu9HhIROx6MOwiEDvmNrHYtA-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl5cSM4bjiAhXOCewKHVgYAkcQ6AEwCHoECBIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22He%20is%20one%20of%20those%20who%20has%20had%20the%20wilderness%20for%20a%20pillow%2C%20and%20called%20a%20star%20his%20brother.%22&f=false) He is *one of those* who ***has*** had the wilderness for a pillow, and called a star ***his*** brother.
> - ✘ He is *one of many* who ***has*** had the wilderness for a pillow, and called a star ***his*** brother.
> - ✔ He is *one of those* who ***have*** had the wilderness for a pillow, and called a star ***their*** brother.
> - ✔ He is *one of many* who ***have*** had the wilderness for a pillow, and called a star ***their*** brother.
> - ✔ He is *someone* who ***has*** had the wilderness for a pillow, and called a star ***his*** brother.

Note that it's semantically ambiguous if what follows the comma is and addition to the entire part before *he* or if it's included in the description of the group. In this case, since I'm talking about groups, I'm interpreting it as being part of the group—although I'd prefer the comma not be there.

And in another construction:

> - [✘](https://www.allure.com/story/kellyanne-conway-postfeminist) I consider myself *one of those* women who ***is*** a product of ***her*** choices, not a victim of ***her*** circumstances.
> - ✘ I consider myself *one of many* women who ***is*** a product of ***her*** choices, not a victim of ***her*** circumstances.
> - ✔ I consider myself *one of those* women who ***are*** a product of ***their*** choices, not a victim of ***their*** circumstances.
> - ✔ I consider myself *one of many* women who ***are*** a product of ***their*** choices, not a victim of ***their*** circumstances.
> - ✔ I consider myself *a woman* who is a product of **her** choices, not a victim of **her** circumstances.

Comment: Devil's advocate here. If the writer had said *"He's not **someone** who makes..."* or *"He is not **one** who makes...”* both would be correct, so why is the verb plural for  *"one of those"* when *one* clearly refers to an individual, i.e. someone?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because you can't say *one of those* and then follow it up with a single item. The syntax itself forces what follows to be a group (or plural list of items) out of which what precedes *one of those* is selected. Since the group is plural, any verb in the phrase has to be plural.

Comment: ["*He is one of those who **has had** the wilderness for a pillow, and called a star his brother.*"](https://books.google.it/books?id=Q5li4S0bpAwC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22He+is+one+of+those+who+has+had+the+wilderness+for+a+pillow,+and+called+a+star+his+brother.%22&source=bl&ots=ax0R92ScTb&sig=ACfU3U0KIu9HhIROx6MOwiEDvmNrHYtA-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl5cSM4bjiAhXOCewKHVgYAkcQ6AEwCHoECBIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22He%20is%20one%20of%20those%20who%20has%20had%20the%20wilderness%20for%20a%20pillow%2C%20and%20called%20a%20star%20his%20brother.%22&f=false)

Comment: and [*He is one of those people who **has seen** the world at close quarters and **has withdrawn** from it.*](http://www.vangoghletters.org/vg/letters/let536/letter.html)

Comment: Here's another interesting example, American Kellyanne Conway said ["*…I consider myself one of those women **who is** a product of **her** choices, not a victim of **her** circumstances."*](https://www.allure.com/story/kellyanne-conway-postfeminist) Using the plural verb *are* and subsequently the plural possessive pronoun *their* would make this sound artificial to my ears. What do you think?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have removed my later comments, updating my answer with their content.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the first part of your answer. [If the noun phrase includes a verb, then subject-verb agreement needs to follow the plural conjugation.] Where is an example with a verb?? Surely, I would say: |One of my friends speaks Italian.| Why use such complicated sentences? And do any of your examples boil down to anything other than that? For me, one of [plural] is followed by a singular verb.

Comment: @Lambie The sentence in the question itself uses a verb (*people who* ***make***, not ***makes***), as does the third example I gave (*party-goers who* ***stay*** *up*, not ***stays*** *up*). It was actually the choice between *make* and *makes* that was the crux of the question.

Comment: “I am one of those people who have good grammar.” is right. https://www.oxonianreview.org/wp/one-of-those-grammatical-errors/ Yes, one of those lawyers who make millions, not makes. I agree. But I don't see that you make this easy to understand. There must be agreement with the antecedent: |One of my friends speaks Italian. |versus |One of my friends who speak Italian hates pasta.|

Comment: @Lambie I agree! ;) It seems like a simple concept to me. But confusion seems to come from understanding what the antecedent actually is. (Not to mention all of the debate over the other subtleties I got into.)

Comment: There's no confusion on my part, I am merely pointing out, with authentic examples,  that speakers, native and non, *sometimes* use the singular verb in that particular construction. You should read the answers in the older question. And if you disagree strongly, which it seems you do, then write an answer there!

Comment: @Mari-LouA There is already a [good answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/232256/291924) there.

Comment: with 6 downvotes...and 9 upvotes