# Subject-verb agreement for adjectival relative clause

Tags: adjectives, verb-agreement, relative-clauses

Which of the following is correct?

> The beaver is one of the few animals that changes its own environment.

Or

> The beaver is one of the few animals that change their own environment.

Comment: The second one. There is a set of a few animals that change their own environment, and the beaver is a member of this set.

Comment: First one's OK, too. There's no other meaning, and the _their_ can be singular.

Comment: *CGEL* say the first is ok too. Here's [a very interesting and informative post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47948/one-of-the-upgrades-that-is-are-being-considered/48078#48078) by your doppelgänger F.E.

Comment: The sentences are amenable to analysis. Leave open.

Comment: No one uses singular "their" for animals! And yes, the first could be seen as also correct, but only as an override. Semantically, the relative clause modifies "animals".

Comment: The second one is correct: *The beaver is one of the few [animals that change their own environment].* Test: *Of the few [animals that change their own environment], the beaver is one.* The first one is incorrect: *\*The beaver is [one] of the few animals [that changes its own environment].* Test: *\*Of the few animals, the beaver is [one that changes its own environment].* (There are more than a few animals.) See my answer at ["You're one of the only people" plurality](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/524298/206976).

Comment: @TinfoilHat [See what. the science says](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47948/one-of-the-upgrades-that-is-are-being-considered/48078#48078)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Not sure what science that is, but the examples there can go either way: *Of those people [who always want to have the last word], he is one.* or *Of those people, he is one [who always wants to have the last word]*. That's because of the deictic *those*. Try swapping in *the few* for *those*. It's different.